# SQL Query to Get Count of Items within a timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need help with an SQL query that will get me a count of hourly  deposits to an account for a specific date. The database consists of deposits and time of deposit to various accounts. I need a query that will return the number deposits made to a certain account on an hourly basis. Ideally the result would look something like this:

MM/DD/YYYY Account XYZ :

12:00PM : 3

1:00PM : 5

2:00PM: 7

3:00PM; 11

*Formatting doesnt really matter, just as long as I can get this info.

Comment: Ive got just a basic query to return a count of items for a specific time frame (11-12): select COUNT(uiDepositID) from RemoteDepositOperationalDBQ.dbo.deposits where sfinancialinstitutionid = '874791778' and convert (char(8),utcreceipttimestamp,108) between '11:00:00' and '12:00:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE @CheckDate DATE
SET @CheckDate='2014/5/13'
SELECT DATEPART(hh, DespositDate), COUNT(1)
FROM table t
WHERE account = 'XYZ' AND CAST(DepositDate AS DATE)=@CheckDate
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, DespositDate)
```

Comment: Hello, Same error as above : "'hour' is not a recognized built-in function name"

Comment: Sorry- Hour should have been DATEPART. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks! that worked... I would like to use this in a SSRS report. If you are familiar with SSRS, how would I make the date a user input field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date/time functions for aggregation.  In your case, this would look like:

```
select cast(DepositDate as date), datepart(hour, DespositDate), count(*)
from table t
where account = 'XYZ'
group by cast(DepositDate as date), datepart(hour, DespositDate);
```

Comment: I get the error " 'hour' is not a recognized built-in function name.
"

Comment: @Tim . . . Sorry about that.  Sometimes I forget:  just because *I* want it there doesn't mean that it is there.